Flutter TextField for uppercase password
I need a TextField for entering a password in uppercase.
I thought it would be easily done like this:
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
          obscureText: true,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

But it doesn't work: it seems like TextCapitalization.characters and obscureText are incompatible, the keyboard is in lowercase... Any idea?
PS. Sometimes it works on Android, but not on iOS...
PPS. The TextInputFormatter solution here does not solve the issue because while it converts input to uppercase, the user is unaware about it because the keyboard is still in lowercase and the typed characters are not visible because of obscureText.

even if the keyboard is in lowercase. have you checked how the entered password looks like if you just type lowercase keys with this setting?

@Thomas Yes it's lowercase of course.

Sorry, just wanted to be sure. Did you take a look into the TextFields source code?

You can't force the keyboard to display uppercase characters while obscureText is enabled, but you can convert the input to uppercase as it is typed using a TextEditingController. And it doesn't make sense to have both enabled, why do you chosen this approach

@G3nt_M3caj It makes sense if the password must be in uppercase, and I don't see why it can't have both enabled.

Legally meaning is allowed, I know. But, usually (if you have seen around) the passwords use to be, ate least a uppercase, at least a lower case, a number and some special char. In your case there have to be all uppercase.. Anyway, good luck!!

Can you try changing your keyboard type to passwordVisible ? example :
TextField(
keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
)

@AbdelazizHADIATALLAH Yes, it doesn't help.

This is NOT a duplicate because the TextInputFormatter does not solve the issue: while it converts input to uppercase, the user is unaware about it because the keyboard is still in lowercase and the typed characters are not visible because of obscureText.

@Patrick Yes that is the problem the user could not notice that , If I find any turn around I will update you .

two options. alert If user type lowercase or no text type text field If user type lowercase
